# FlatList scrollToIndex using useRef with Typescript - Type Error

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, react-hooks

I am working with FlatList and I want to create one ref to be able to scroll the FlatList when pressing one button.

The thing is that I am using Typescript and I am having one type error that I am not able to solve.

The question is, **how do I create an interface for a FlatList ref?**

There we have one example of what I am doing.

```
let flatListRef = useRef();

<FlatList
  ref={flatListRef} // Error Here
  data={store.data}
  ... />

<Button 
  onPress={() =>
    flatListRef.current.scrollToIndex({index:index})
  } />
```

The type error that I am having is when I set the ref into the FlatList

The error says:

> Overload 1 of 2, '(props: FlatListProps<{ data: string; type: number;
> id: number; }> | Readonly<FlatListProps<{ data: string; type: number;
> id: number; }>>): FlatList<...>', gave the following error.
> Type 'MutableRefObject' is not assignable to type 'LegacyRef<FlatList<{ data: string; type: number; id: number; }>> |
> undefined'.
> Type 'MutableRefObject' is not assignable to type 'RefObject<FlatList<{ data: string; type: number; id: number; }>>'.
> Types of property 'current' are incompatible.
> Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'FlatList<{ data: string; type: number; id: number; }> | null'.
>
> Overload 2 of 2, '(props: FlatListProps<{ data: string; type:
> number; id: number; }>, context: any): FlatList<{ data: string; type:
> number; id: number; }>', gave the following error.
> Type 'MutableRefObject' is not assignable to type 'LegacyRef<FlatList<{ data: string; type: number; id: number; }>> |
> undefined'.

When I set the type to the ref when I create it, the error does not solve, something like:

```
interface ListProps {
  data: string;
  type: number;
  id: number;
 }

let flatListRef = useRef<ListProps>()
```

Or do I need to pass the data structure or something as initialValue when I create the useRef hook?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Your `flatListRef` is a `ref` to a `FlatList` instance.  So that's what you'll want to use as your generic type parameter.

Refs to DOM elements expect an initial value of `null` rather than `undefined`, so you'll need to fix that as well.

```
const flatListRef = useRef<FlatList>(null);
```

You'll want to use the optional chaining `?.` when you access the ref just in case `.current` is still `null`.

```
flatListRef.current?.scrollToIndex({index})
```

[TypeScript Playground Link](https://tsplay.dev/wO8ylN)

Comment: That is exactly what I want. Thank you so much :)