# Is there a way to know the exact type of props coming from a parent element in TypeScript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, use-ref

I'm using TypeScript with React Native to develop a mobile app.
To restore the scroll position of the previous screen, I created a variable and assign the `useRef()` to handle the scroll.
What is the type for the ref prop?
I'll share my code below.

```
const sectionListRef = useRef();
...
sectionListRef.current.ScrollToLocation // <-- Property 'scrollToLocation' does not exist on type 'never';
```

I have no idea which type should be...
Can someone please tell me why this error happens and how I resolve this?

Comment: on what type of HTML element do you use the ref? - depending on that element the type changes. (so is the ref on a div, or input for example)

Comment: The name indicates that it would be react-native `SectionList`, and at least the react-native [docs](https://reactnative.dev/docs/sectionlist) does not seem to specify the type about this either.

Comment: @Lord-JulianXLII This is used react native SectionList

Comment: @JohnLi Yeah right... so its type should be `any` ?

Comment: try useRef(null) - when using useRef() with typescript you should always pass an initial value (at some point you'll have to assert/narrow, that sectionListRef is not null)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did find a similar [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69247591/20436957) for `FlatList`, perhaps try if this could help:

```
const sectionListRef = useRef<SectionList>(null);
```

When using `.scrollToLocation()`:

[More about `scrollToLocation`](https://reactnative.dev/docs/sectionlist#scrolltolocation)

```
sectionListRef.current?.scrollToLocation(param);
```

I couldn't find any offical guide for this though, but hopefully these would help as a reference.

Answer (score 0):

This syntax maybe help you:

For example:

```
const someRef = useRef<Your Type>(Your Initial Value);
```

You should specify type and initial value.

Comment: This is not a solution, even though I specify type and initial value, but still shows the error